# PHP preg_match: comma separated decimals

Tags: php, regex

This regex finds the right string, but only returns the first result. How do I make it search the rest of the text?

```
$text =",415.2109,520.33970,495.274100,482.3238,741.5634
655.3444,488.29980,741.5634";

preg_match("/[^,]+[\d+][.?][\d+]*/",$text,$data);

echo $data;
```

Follow up:
I'm pushing the initial expectations of this script, and I'm at the point where I'm pulling out more verbose data.  Wasted many hours with this...can anyone shed some light?
heres my string:

```
155.101.153.123:simple:mass_mid:[479.0807,99.011, 100.876],mass_tol:[30],mass_mode:  [1],adducts:[M+CH3OH+H],
130.216.138.250:simple:mass_mid:[290.13465,222.34566],mass_tol:[30],mass_mode:[1],adducts:[M+Na],
```

and heres my regex:
"/mass_mid:[((?:\d+)(?:.)(?:\d+)(?:,)*)/"

I'm really banging my head on this one! Can someone tell me how to exclude the line **mass_mid:[** from the results, and keep the comma seperated values?

Comment: If the text is so nicely formatted, why not simply use `explode`?

Comment: Well your regex doesn't make sense, you're putting everything in a character class. Use `/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/` instead.

Comment: Your regex will fail on the string "123.45"

Comment: Thanks HamZa, it's in order now, perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preg_match_all` rather than `preg_match`

From the PHP Manual:

```
(`preg_match_all`) searches subject for all matches to the regular expression given in pattern and puts them in matches in the order specified by flags.

After the first match is found, the subsequent searches are continued on from end of the last match.
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Thank you, that helped immensely.  How can I get the regex to omit newline characters?

Comment: If you mean only to match lines, you'll have to enclose you regexp between ^ and $: /^[^,]+[\d+][.?][\d+]*$/

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a regex.  Use `split` to split apart your inputs on the commas.

Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings.

Comment: `split` is deprecated and is now recommended to use `preg_split` instead or `explode` if regex is not required.

Answer (score 0):

## Description

To extract a list of numeric values which may include a single decimal point, then you could use this regex

`\d*\.?\d+`

[image]

## PHP Code Example:

```
<?php
$sourcestring=",415.2109,520.33970,495.274100,482.3238,741.5634
655.3444,488.29980,741.5634";
preg_match_all('/\d*\.?\d+/im',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>
```

yields matches

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 415.2109
            [1] => 520.33970
            [2] => 495.274100
            [3] => 482.3238
            [4] => 741.5634
            [5] => 655.3444
            [6] => 488.29980
            [7] => 741.5634
        )

)
```